# Cannot display the SVG from SVGSVGElement in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xml, svg, innerhtml

I have a SVG object serialized into a string in the React State. I want to display it on screen, but keep failing to doing so. If I paste manually the SVG's XML data in an inline manner, it works. But I need to take it from the State. Also, I would like to avoid the method `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

I have tried to parse it from the string and then set it to the innerHTML object like this:

```
let SVG_file = this.state.SVG;
var parser = new DOMParser();
var svg = parser.parseFromString(SVG_file, "image/svg+xml");

return (
        document.getElementsByName('Container').innerHTML = svg.documentElement
    )
```

I receive the following error when executing the code above:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object SVGSVGElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

If instead, in the return above, I change it by either of the following 2 lines (changes are **outerHTML** and **innerHTML**):

```
document.getElementsByName('Container').innerHTML = svg.documentElement.outerHTML
document.getElementsByName('Container').innerHTML = svg.documentElement.innerHTML
```

React renders the content of the XML in plain text, not as a component.

Any suggestions on how to display the SVG itself? Thanks in advance!

P.S.: In case it helps, the SVG that worked as inline declaration was this one:

```
var XML = <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="145" height="145">
        <path transform="scale(5)" className="qrline" stroke="#00008b"
              d="M4 4.5h7m1 0h1m2 0h2m1 0h7m-21 1h1m5 0h1m5 0h1m1 0h1m5 0h1m-21 1h1m1 0h3m1 0h1m3 0h1m3 0h1m1 0h3m1 0h1m-21 1h1m1 0h3m1 0h1m1 0h3m1 0h1m1 0h1m1 0h3m1 0h1m-21 1h1m1 0h3m1 0h1m2 0h1m1 0h1m2 0h1m1 0h3m1 0h1m-21 1h1m5 0h1m3 0h3m1 0h1m5 0h1m-21 1h7m1 0h1m1 0h1m1 0h1m1 0h7m-12 1h4m-11 1h1m1 0h3m1 0h2m3 0h1m3 0h1m2 0h1m-13 1h1m1 0h2m1 0h3m1 0h4m-21 1h1m3 0h1m1 0h1m1 0h2m4 0h1m1 0h1m2 0h2m-21 1h3m1 0h2m1 0h1m1 0h1m1 0h1m2 0h1m1 0h1m-17 1h1m2 0h1m1 0h4m2 0h2m1 0h2m3 0h2m-13 1h2m1 0h2m1 0h3m2 0h1m-20 1h7m2 0h2m4 0h6m-21 1h1m5 0h1m1 0h1m1 0h1m1 0h1m1 0h2m4 0h1m-21 1h1m1 0h3m1 0h1m1 0h3m4 0h1m3 0h2m-21 1h1m1 0h3m1 0h1m2 0h1m2 0h1m1 0h3m1 0h2m-20 1h1m1 0h3m1 0h1m1 0h1m2 0h2m2 0h4m1 0h1m-21 1h1m5 0h1m2 0h1m5 0h1m3 0h1m-20 1h7m2 0h6m1 0h2m1 0h2"/>
    </svg>

return (
    document.getElementsByName('Container').innerHTML = XML
)
```

Comment: The getElementsByName() method returns a collection of elements. Please try document.getElementsByName('SalesQRCodeWindow')[0].innerHTML = XML

Comment: That line was working well. After your replacement, it throws the following error: `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined`